# Supervisor in Docker doesn't work

Tags: docker, supervisord

I have a problem with `supervisor` in `docker`. I use the `supervisor` to start 4 `.sh` scripts: `datagrid.sh`, `ml.sh`, `startmap.sh` and `dirwatcher.sh`.

When I open the container, navigate to the scripts directory and try to start the scripts manually, everything works, the scripts all start, but they don't start on start time. I assume the problem is with the supervisor. Thank you.

The error:

```
2018-08-08 12:28:08,512 INFO spawned: 'datagrid' with pid 171
2018-08-08 12:28:08,514 INFO spawned: 'dirwatcher' with pid 172 
2018-08-08 12:28:08,517 INFO spawned: 'startmap' with pid 173 
2018-08-08 12:28:08,519 INFO spawned: 'ml' with pid 175 
2018-08-08 12:28:08,520 INFO exited: datagrid (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-08-08 12:28:08,520 INFO exited: dirwatcher (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-08-08 12:28:08,520 INFO exited: startmap (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-08-08 12:28:08,520 INFO exited: ml (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-08-08 12:28:08,527 INFO gave up: datagrid entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2018-08-08 12:28:08,532 INFO gave up: ml entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2018-08-08 12:28:08,537 INFO gave up: startmap entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2018-08-08 12:28:08,539 INFO gave up: dirwatcher entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

My `supervisord.conf` file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=false

[program:datagrid]
command=sh /EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_data_grid.sh start -D

[program:dirwatcher]
command=sh /EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_dirwatcher.sh start -D

[program:startmap]
command=sh /EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_startmap.sh start -D

[program:ml]
command=sh /EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_ml.sh start -D
```

I use alpine linux in the container.

Comment: Try https://immortal.run some people have been using it within docker: https://github.com/immortal/immortal/issues/34#issuecomment-362082580

Comment: I'm new to docker, can you give me a little bit more info ?

Comment: Probably this can help: https://github.com/nbari/docker/tree/master/immortal it will keep up and running this https://github.com/nbari/docker/blob/master/immortal/sleep.yml

Comment: Hello, I can't seem to make `immortal.run` start working. I don't understand where to specify the scripts I want to run inside the container. Can you help me ?

Comment: Hi, just clone the repo https://github.com/nbari/docker/tree/master/immortal and within the dir do `docker build -t test-immortal` and then `docker run -it --privileged test-immortal .`

Comment: I did that and it says `start.sh no such file or directory`.

Comment: And how do I use it to start the script in my container ?

Answer (score 8):

There are few problems here

1. The following statement:

   [supervisord]
   nodaemon=false

This makes the Supervisord run as daemon and the container needs a main process.

Try changing it to

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
```

This configuration makes Supervisord itself run as a foreground process, which will keep the container up and running.

2. From the logs
   '520 INFO exited: datagrid (exit status 0; not expected)'

Supervisord is not able to recognise 0 as valid exit code and is exiting the process. Add the following to the conf for all the processes. This will tell Supervisord to try restarting the process only if the exit code is not 0

```
[program:datagrid]
command=sh /EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_data_grid.sh start -D
autorestart=unexpected
exitcodes=0
```

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to a similar problem and this worked like a charm!

Comment: Why we can't have 2  main process? Do we need the configuration out of the docker context ? and if we are using apache, why supervisor stop apache also ?

Comment: IDK what happened. I was using **nodaemon=false** and in my entrypoint I used **service supervisor start** it worked fine. IDK why. but that worked 